# Using Accessibility Service Android

Tags: android, android-service, accessibility-api

I have made use of Accessibility service in android to detect the foreground application.

I want to listen to 2 of the available accessibility events

> **TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED**
>
> **TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED**

I want to listen to all `window state change` events, that is working, but for second event, i want to listen to `view_text_changed` event of only 1-2 applications and not all.

I have read & tried the `android:packageNames` parameter in xml, but then it will impose limitation on window_state_changed event.

Is there any other way to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't way to specify interesting package names for specified accessibility events. You have to just use [AccessibilityEvent#getPackageName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#getPackageName()) to filter interesting you packages.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have setup your `AndroidManifest` to recognise an `AccessibilityService`, I am adding the other required code here just in case someone wants a direct answer.

Accessibility service configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeViewTextChanged"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.accessibility.ServiceSettingsActivity"/>
```

Note the `android:accessibilityEventTypes` are as needed. If you limit the package in xml you won't get the `TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` as rightly pointed out in the question.

So, you also need to make changes in your implementation of the `AccessibilityService`.

```
public class VoiceAccessibilityService extends android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService {
    private static String TAG = VoiceAccessibilityService.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED && event.getPackageName().equals("Your package names")) {
            Logger.d(TAG + " SHOW " + event.toString());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Logger.d(TAG + " interrupt");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!